# How to disable copy/ download access for editors in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to restrict access on google sheets so that only an  "owner" can download/ copy a document.

Currently the files only allow folks tagged to viewer/ commenter access to be disabled

Is there a script that i can use to extend this to folks tagged to "editor" access as well.

Thanks

Comment: No it's not possible to disable it for editors.

Answer (score 0):

As comment by James D and as seen on the [Google Support page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en&visit_id=1-636588785709077336-3170658176&rd=1)

> When you share a file with someone, you can choose what they can do with it.
>
> View: People can view, but can’t change or share the file with others.
>
> Comment: People can make comments and suggestions, but can’t change or
> share the file with others.
>
> Edit: People can make changes, accept or
> reject suggestions, and share the file with others.

So if you want to restrict access to some documents, spreadsheets, any file, you must change the user's permission.